# Cannot mount partitions from image

Tags: linux, mount, lvm, gpt, disk-image

I have a `dd` image of an old SSD. It's been sitting on an external HDD for a while, but I have previously been able to mount the image and its partitions. Now, for some reason, I can only mount the EFI partition (the first partition) but the filesystems for the rest are not recognized. Furthermore, a LVM2 partition is no longer detected at all.

Mounting the img file:

```
ubuntu > sudo losetup -f -P /mnt/d/Disks/Toshiba/ssd-backup.gpt.img
ubuntu > lsblk
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0       7:0    0 238.5G  0 loop
├─loop0p1 259:0    0   100M  0 part
├─loop0p2 259:1    0   128M  0 part
├─loop0p3 259:2    0    50G  0 part
├─loop0p4 259:3    0   200M  0 part
├─loop0p5 259:4    0   200M  0 part
├─loop0p6 259:5    0    50G  0 part
└─loop0p7 259:6    0   100G  0 part
...
```

Checking the partition info for the image & the mount points to ensure they are the same:

```
ubuntu > gdisk -l /mnt/d/Disks/Toshiba/ssd-backup.gpt.img
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /mnt/d/Disks/Toshiba/ssd-backup.gpt.img: 500118192 sectors, 238.5 GiB
Sector size (logical): 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 74230653-CCAA-49B1-B5F7-7A901F6960BE
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 500118158
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 79400926 sectors (37.9 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          206847   100.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   2          206848          468991   128.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   3          468992       105326591   50.0 GiB    0700  Basic data partition
   4       105326592       105736191   200.0 MiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   5       105736192       106145791   200.0 MiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   6       106145792       211003391   50.0 GiB    0700  Basic data partition
   7       290402304       500118158   100.0 GiB   8E00  Linux LVM

ubuntu > sudo gdisk -l /dev/loop0
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/loop0: 500118192 sectors, 238.5 GiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 74230653-CCAA-49B1-B5F7-7A901F6960BE
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 500118158
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 79400926 sectors (37.9 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          206847   100.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   2          206848          468991   128.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   3          468992       105326591   50.0 GiB    0700  Basic data partition
   4       105326592       105736191   200.0 MiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   5       105736192       106145791   200.0 MiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   6       106145792       211003391   50.0 GiB    0700  Basic data partition
   7       290402304       500118158   100.0 GiB   8E00  Linux LVM
```

`lsblk` does not detect any file systems anywhere for whatever reason:

```
ubuntu > sudo lsblk -f
NAME      FSTYPE LABEL UUID FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0
├─loop0p1
├─loop0p2
├─loop0p3
├─loop0p4
├─loop0p5
├─loop0p6
└─loop0p7
sda
sdb
sdc                          236.1G     1% /
```

Attempting to mount one of the Linux filesystems (partition 4 but trying 5 is the same):

```
ubuntu > sudo mount /dev/loop0p4 /tmp/mnt
mount: /tmp/mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0p4, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
ubuntu > sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/loop0p4 /tmp/mnt
mount: /tmp/mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0p4, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
ubuntu > sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/loop0p4 /tmp/mnt
mount: /tmp/mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0p4, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
ubuntu > sudo mount -t btrfs /dev/loop0p4 /tmp/mnt
mount: /tmp/mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0p4, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
ubuntu > sudo btrfs device scan -d /dev/loop0p4
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
ubuntu >
```

Trying to scan for LVM filesystems:

```
ubuntu > sudo pvdisplay /dev/loop0p7
  Failed to find physical volume "/dev/loop0p7".
ubuntu > sudo pvscan
  No matching physical volumes found
ubuntu > sudo lvdisplay /dev/loop0p7
  Volume group "loop0p7" not found
  Cannot process volume group loop0p7
ubuntu > sudo vgscan
ubuntu > sudo vgdisplay
ubuntu >
```

Despite all this, the disk image and first partition mount properly:

```
ubuntu > sudo mount /dev/loop0p1 /tmp/mnt
ubuntu > ll /tmp/mnt
total 11531
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    1024 Dec 31  1969 ./
drwxrwxrwt 12 root root    4096 Jan 23 19:44 ../
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root    1024 Sep  4  2014 EFI/
```

I have no idea where to go from here. I've tried 5 ways from Sunday to mount the filesystems in these partitions with no success. I even extracted the partition img files from the disk img, and couldn't work with those either (so it doesn't seem to be caused by the partition being part of a larger disk image).

```
ubuntu > sudo losetup -f -P /mnt/d/Disks/Toshiba/ssd-backup.gpt/6.Linux\ LVM.img
ubuntu > lsblk
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0       7:0    0 238.5G  0 loop
├─loop0p1 259:0    0   100M  0 part /tmp/mnt
├─loop0p2 259:1    0   128M  0 part
├─loop0p3 259:2    0    50G  0 part
├─loop0p4 259:3    0   200M  0 part
├─loop0p5 259:4    0   200M  0 part
├─loop0p6 259:5    0    50G  0 part
└─loop0p7 259:6    0   100G  0 part
loop1       7:1    0   100G  0 loop
sda         8:0    0   256G  0 disk
sdb         8:16   0 339.8M  1 disk
sdc         8:32   0   256G  0 disk /
ubuntu > sudo pvdisplay /dev/loop1
  Failed to find physical volume "/dev/loop1".
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I need to figure out how to recover this data.

Comment: What does `file -s /dev/loop0p?` say? As a general comment, it is sensible to either make the mounts read-only or else have a copy of the image file. If this is potentially valuable data then you don't want to risk automatic changes to it as it is being mounted.

Comment: I've been trying ro and rw (working off a copy of the file so if I fubar it I can just make another copy. `file` just says `data` for all partitions, no filesystem info even for the EFI partition (p1) that mounts successfully

Comment: Great that you are working off a copy! Lets try doing things a little more manually. `losetup -o 52663296K /dev/loop0 /mnt/d/Disks/Toshiba/ssd-backup.gpt.img; file -s /dev/loop0; losetup -d /dev/loop9` -if it doesn't report "data" then you could try mounting it. Just to make sure we are on the same page, the info shown by gdisk about the partitions comes from the gpt table,not from the partitions themselves.

Comment: Results: https://pastebin.com/ni5ZAFMk

Comment: That is a pity! I would try running https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk (probably available through your package manager) on the image next, asking it to find any filesystems in the image.

Comment: testdisk says that the partition has no LVM structures, I'm trying to run recovery now but i think it's all gone

Comment: I am sorry but I think you are right..

Comment: I was able to get it! I had to use the original img file with testdisk (there was some issue with partitions in the copy) and now my lvm works